# SharePoint get current user accountname?

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-2010

Does SharePoint 2010 store the current user's accountname somewhere in a globally accessible JS object?

Every solution I can find involves some variation of an ajax web service call and this seems like an extremely heavy solution to access what should be a trivial piece of information.

**Things I can access easily:**

- Get current user id from `__spUserId`
- Get current user name by scraping the html of the ribbon (eg: `$('#zz17_Menu').text()`)

But neither of these is the accountname.

**Things I would rather not do:**

- Get current user info with a SOAP call to GetUserProfileByName
- Get current user info by making an Ajax call for ../_layouts/userdisp.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone else who stumbles across this, a year later I figured out how.

To your master page [register SPSWC](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5d4277fe-40d1-449b-a79a-421fddee9bd9/show-accounts-first-name-in-sharepoint-through-masterpage) (if you're using Randy Drisgill's [starter master](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/) it will already be there).

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SPSWC" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Then, before you want to access a property (eg: UserName) pull in the data

```
<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyLoader runat="server"/>
```

Next, access one of the properties, I would recommend using TitleMode to embed it in a `<script>` element.

```
<script>
  var username = '<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue PropertyName="UserName" TitleMode="true" runat="server"/>';
</script>
```

We now use it as shown in this [PasteBin demo](http://pastebin.com/HG6pdpwe) to populate a global with a few properties like first name, last name, user name, profile picture, status.

Comment: great idea and a good alternative to resorting to async calls to SharePoint services. Also works pretty well with angular, since you can then define an angular value with the user data at app bootstrap time instead of using an angular service to "lazy load" the user info.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to make a web service call to do it reliably. Thankfully, SPServices makes it quick and painless to do so.

http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$%28%29.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser

```
$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "Name",
    debug: false
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately "quick and painless" for me, does not mean quick and painless for my application. SPServices uses that second route I mentioned, it brings in a complete copy of ../_layouts/userdisp.aspx which in my environment is 22KB of data which takes over a second to retrieve, then gets jQuery to initialise the entire response as a document fragment, and finally drills down to get your info. That is akin to me building a house and waiting for you to write your name on the mailbox.

Comment: If performance is your goal then I suggest writing a custom REST service that takes the user id and returns the user name. That way, all the heavy lifting can be done on the server side.